# Get all overlapping date ranges when all overlap at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I'm struggling with this for a few days... trying to write an SQL query to get all date ranges when all units overlap at the same time. It's better to see it graphically.

Here is the simplified table with the image for reference:
[image]

```
UnitId  Start       End
======  ==========  ==========
1       05/01/2018  09/01/2018
1       10/01/2018  13/01/2018
2       04/01/2018  15/01/2018
2       19/01/2018  23/01/2018
3       06/01/2018  12/01/2018
3       14/01/2018  22/01/2018
```

Expected result:

```
Start       End
======      ========== 
06/01/2018  09/01/2018
10/01/2018  12/01/2018
```

What I currently have:

```
DECLARE @sourceTable TABLE (UnitId int, StartDate datetime, EndDate datetime);
INSERT INTO @sourceTable VALUES
 (1, '2018-01-05', '2018-01-09')
,(1, '2018-01-10', '2018-01-13')
,(2, '2018-01-04', '2018-01-15')
,(2, '2018-01-19', '2018-01-23')
,(3, '2018-01-06', '2018-01-12')
,(3, '2018-01-14', '2018-01-22');

SELECT DISTINCT
 (SELECT max(v) FROM (values(A.StartDate), (B.StartDate)) as value(v)) StartDate
,(SELECT min(v) FROM (values(A.EndDate), (B.EndDate)) as value(v)) EndDate
FROM @sourceTable A 
JOIN @sourceTable B 
ON A.startDate <= B.endDate AND A.endDate >= B.startDate AND A.UnitId != B.UnitId
```

Comment: can you show your sql as to what you have tried so far so that we can help refine this. Also, can you create a SQL Fiddle that will help us help you

Comment: Here's some help... https://developer42.wordpress.com/2016/12/19/filtering-on-a-date-window/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is "count number of overlapping intervals" problem ([this picture should help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8xRs.png)). Here is one solution to it:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (UnitId INT, [Start] DATE, [End] DATE);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, '2018-01-05', '2018-01-09'),
(1, '2018-01-10', '2018-01-13'),
(2, '2018-01-04', '2018-01-15'),
(2, '2018-01-19', '2018-01-23'),
(3, '2018-01-06', '2018-01-12'),
(3, '2018-01-14', '2018-01-22');

WITH cte1(date, val) AS (
    SELECT [Start], 1 FROM @t AS t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [End], 0 FROM @t AS t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [End]), -1 FROM @t AS t
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT date, SUM(val) OVER (ORDER BY date, val) AS usage
    FROM cte1
)
SELECT date, MAX(usage) AS usage
FROM cte2
GROUP BY date
```

It will give you a list of all dates at which the use count (possibly) changed:

```
date          usage
2018-01-04    1
2018-01-05    2
2018-01-06    3
2018-01-09    3
2018-01-10    3
2018-01-12    3
2018-01-13    2
2018-01-14    2
2018-01-15    2
2018-01-16    1
2018-01-19    2
2018-01-22    2
2018-01-23    1
2018-01-24    0
```

With this approach you do not need a calendar table or rCTE to build missing dates. Converting the above to ranges (`2018-01-05 ... 2018-01-15`, `2018-01-19 ... 2018-01-22` etc) is not very difficult.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (UnitId INT, [Start] DATE, [End] DATE);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, '2018-01-05', '2018-01-09'),
(1, '2018-01-10', '2018-01-13'),
(2, '2018-01-04', '2018-01-15'),
(2, '2018-01-19', '2018-01-23'),
(3, '2018-01-06', '2018-01-12'),
(3, '2018-01-14', '2018-01-22');

WITH cte1(date, val) AS (
    SELECT [Start], 1 FROM @t AS t                 -- starting date increments counter
    UNION ALL                                      
    SELECT [End], 0 FROM @t AS t                   -- we need all edges in the result
    UNION ALL                                      
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [End]), -1 FROM @t AS t -- end date + 1 decrements counter
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT date, SUM(val) OVER (ORDER BY date, val) AS usage -- running sum for counter
    FROM cte1
), cte3 AS (
    SELECT date, MAX(usage) AS usage -- group multiple events on same date together
    FROM cte2
    GROUP BY date
), cte4 AS (
    SELECT date, usage, CASE
        WHEN usage > 1 AND LAG(usage) OVER (ORDER BY date) > 1 THEN 0
        WHEN usage < 2 AND LAG(usage) OVER (ORDER BY date) < 2 THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END AS chg -- start new group if prev and curr usage are on opposite side of 1
    FROM cte3
), cte5 AS (
    SELECT date, usage, SUM(chg) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS grp -- number groups for each change
    FROM cte4
)
SELECT MIN(date) date1, MAX(date) date2
FROM cte5
GROUP BY grp
HAVING MIN(usage) > 1
```

Result:

```
date1         date2
2018-01-05    2018-01-15
2018-01-19    2018-01-22
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for date ranges where all units overlap. So look for start dates where all units exist and end dates where all units exist and then join the two.

I'm using `ROW_NUMBER` to join the first start date with the first end date, the second start date with the second end date and so on.

```
select s.startdate, e.enddate
from
(
  select startdate, row_number() over (order by startdate) as rn
  from @sourceTable s1
  where 
  (
    select count(*)
    from @sourceTable s2
    where s1.startdate between s2.startdate and s2.enddate
  ) = (select count(distinct unitid) from @sourceTable)
) s
join
(
  select enddate, row_number() over (order by startdate) as rn
  from @sourceTable s1
  where 
  (
    select count(*)
    from @sourceTable s2
    where s1.enddate between s2.startdate and s2.enddate
  ) = (select count(distinct unitid) from @sourceTable)
) e on e.rn = s.rn
order by s.startdate;
```

There may be more elegant ways to solve this, but I guess this query is at least easy to understand :-)

Rextester demo: https://rextester.com/GRRSW89045