# how to calculate occupancy on the basis of admission and discharge dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, postgresql-13

Suppose I have patient admission/claim wise data like the sample below.  Data type of patient_id and hosp_id columns is `VARCHAR`

Table name `claims`

| rec_no | patient_id | hosp_id | admn_date | discharge_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 01-01-2020 | 10-01-2020 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 31-12-2019 | 11-01-2020 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 11-01-2020 | 15-01-2020 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | 04-01-2020 | 10-01-2020 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 16-01-2020 | 17-01-2020 |
| 6 | 4 | 2 | 01-01-2020 | 10-01-2020 |
| 7 | 5 | 2 | 02-01-2020 | 11-01-2020 |
| 8 | 6 | 2 | 03-01-2020 | 12-01-2020 |
| 9 | 7 | 2 | 04-01-2020 | 13-01-2020 |
| 10 | 2 | 1 | 31-12-2019 | 10-01-2020 |

I have another table wherein bed strength/max occupancy strength of hospitals are stored.

table name `beds`

| hosp_id | bed_strength |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

**Expected Results**  I want to find out hospital-wise dates where its declared bed-strength has exceeded on any day.

**Code I have tried**  Nothing as I am new to SQL.  However, I can solve this in R with the following strategy

- `pivot_longer` the dates
- `tidyr::complete()` missing dates in between
- `summarise` or `aggregate` results for each date.

Simultaneously, I also want to know that whether it can be done without pivoting (if any) in sql because in the `claims` table there are 15 million + rows and pivoting really really slows down the process.  Please help.

Comment: You need to count overlapping intervals. Various solutions exist.

Comment: can you provide me link with any one of them?

Comment: Try the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53495546). Basically you use union all to create a set of entry and exit dates, then perform a running sum... increase it on entry and decrease it on exit. The dates with sum greater than x are your target.

Comment: @AnilGoyal can you also add the expected results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()` to do something very similar in Postgres.  For the occupancy by date:

```
select c.hosp_id, gs.date, count(*) as occupanyc
from claims c cross join lateral
     generate_series(admn_date, discharge_date, interval '1 day') gs(date)
group by c.hosp_id, gs.date;
```

Then use this as a subquery to get the dates that exceed the threshold:

```
select hd.*, b.strength
from (select c.hosp_id, gs.date, count(*) as occupancy
      from claims c cross join lateral
           generate_series(c.admn_date, c.discharge_date, interval '1 day') gs(date)
      group by c.hosp_id, gs.date
     ) hd join
     beds b
     using (hosp_id)
where h.occupancy > b.strength
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon for the help.  It works.  I wasn't aware of this `generate series` yet.  I think it works something like `tidyr::complete()` in `r`

Comment: Can you please explain what is `lateral` doing here?  I am trying to understand the syntax

Comment: @AnilGoyal . . . In this case, nothing actually because Postgres allows `generate_series()` to refer to columns in previously defined tables.  However, this is really an example of a lateral join, so I like to be explicit.